# Why do I need enp0s8?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm set up a DNS server in Virtualbox with 4 VMs, one server (Debian10) and three clients (2 Debia10 and 1 Win7). In Virtualbox the VMs have adapter 1 with te same internal network and adapter 2 as NAT. Each VM have a static IP so in Linux VM's I edited `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
   # The loopback network interface
      auto lo
      iface lo inet loopback

   # Primary network interface
     auto enp0s3
     iface enp0s3 inet static
     address 192.168.3.1
     netmask 255.255.255.0
```

In this first configuration I did't put the enp0s8 interface. Then, after restart the networking service I realize that I could ping internet ips with success, such 8.8.8.8.

In a second configuration I added the enp0s8 to the file as follow:

```
# Secondly network interface
  auto enp0s8
  iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

Then I disabled the enp0s8 with `ifdown enp0s8` and lost conectivity with the internet.

If I was able to ping internet ips without enp0s8 in the file `/etc/network/interfaces` why do I need this interface? And if the interface is not mandatory why if added and then disable the conectivity is lost?
Thanks